# Kubernetes liveness probe fails when the logs show a 200 response

Tags: django, kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

I am using https://pypi.org/project/django-health-check/ for my health checks in a Django app run through [kubernetes_wsgi](https://github.com/coderanger/kubernetes-wsgi) with the following YAML:

```yaml
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /ht/
            port: 8020
            httpHeaders:
              - name: Host
                value: pdt-staging.nagyv.com
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 10
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /ht/
            port: 8020
            httpHeaders:
              - name: Host
                value: pdt-staging.nagyv.com
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          timeoutSeconds: 5
```

The pod logs claim that the probe was successful:

`INFO:twisted:"-" - - [22/Jul/2022:22:11:07 +0000] "GET /ht/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1411 "-" "kube-probe/1.22"`

At the same time, the pod events deny this:

`Liveness probe failed: Get "http://10.2.1.43:8020/ht/": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)`

... and after a while, the pod regularly restarts.

The pod seems to be fully functional. I can reach the `/ht/` endpoint as well. Everything seems to work, except for the liveness probes.

I read about slow responses causing the issue, but this is pretty fast.

Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: how long does the request take? you don't define `timeoutSeconds` on the livenessProbe so it defaults to 1 second. it could be that the successful requests you are seeing are from the readinessProbe that has a 5 second timeout defined but the livenessProbe is timing out because the 1 second is too short.

Answer (score 0):

python containers usually take high memory, in general to others. When you are running django behind a gunicorn, container by default utilize around 150M (for me) of your memory (depends on your amount of source code too[for us the source code was around 50M]). It too depends on the pip packages installed on the container for your app. Its good practise to provide usually 20% high memory than expected for django with gunicorn. You should also increase the `timeoutSeconds` to `30` or `20` according to the amount of traffic you are handling in one container. Plus , either have `readinessProbe` or `livenessProbe` on the container, both the probes will create too much noisy traffic to the container. Plus ,use HPA to scale your app, scale the app at 60% cpu and 60% memory to control burst of traffic.

As you are using threads , be careful around number of active connections on db. You are also exporting django health metrics (to `prometheus`) which is addition to the app functionality, remember to add extra resources for that too. `prometheus` scraping can also create too much overhead on the container too , so choose the number of prometheus scraping the same container and `scrape_interval` wisely. You don't want your container just to serve just the internal traffic.

For more relevant reference to this problem : https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/89898